# Why optional permission grant allowed by user but not detected in chrome.permissions.contains function?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension. What is weird is that it's working perfect on local (using the "Load unpacked folder" way).

However, when I submitted it to the Chrome Web Store, it's not working.

Here are details:

In `manifest.json`:

```
"optional_permissions": [ "\u003Call_urls"],
"permissions": [ "activeTab", "contextMenus" ],
```

In `option.js`:

```
// First of all, check whether I've got the permissions
chrome.permissions.contains({
  origins: ['\u003Call_urls>']
}, function(result) {
  if (result) {
    // If I have the permission, remove the "grant" button.
    $('#grant_button').remove();
  } else {
    // If I don't have the permission, let the "grant" button be able to invoke a permission request
    $('#grant_button').click(function(){
      chrome.permissions.request({
        origins: ['\u003Call_urls>']
      }, function(granted) {}
    });
  }
});
```

It's weird that everything works perfectly in local mode:

1. The grant button is enabled at first
2. When I click the grant button, the permission confirming box is there.
3. When I click the "Allow" button and refresh my option page, the grant button is gone.

But in a released version on Chrome Web Store:

1. The grant button is enabled at first
2. When I click the grant button, the permission confirming box is there.
3. When I click the "Allow" button and refresh my option page, the grant button is STILL there. And the `chrome.permissions.contains` did return a false. And there's no way to call `chrome.permissions.request` again.

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/931816 broken in 72 and fixed in 74 i.e. in beta/dev/canary.

Comment: Thanks. I used `tabs` to fix everything.